# Faster multiplication than *

Tags: c, time, multiplication

I am trying to find a faster way than regular multiplication. I run the code in vscode, and as far as I can see I have no optimization enabled. I also tried **gcc -O0 _.c -o _** but still getting the same result. I also write the same code in M0 Assembly but the regular multiplication was again the fastest. Is there anything I am missing, maybe with time calculations, or is regular multiplication really the fastest way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int max(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

uint64_t karatsuba(uint64_t x, uint64_t y) {
    if (x < 10 || y < 10) {
        return x * y;
    }

    int n = max(log10(x) + 1, log10(y) + 1) / 2;

    uint64_t a = x / (uint64_t)pow(10, n);
    uint64_t b = x % (uint64_t)pow(10, n);
    uint64_t c = y / (uint64_t)pow(10, n);
    uint64_t d = y % (uint64_t)pow(10, n);

    uint64_t ac = karatsuba(a, c);
    uint64_t bd = karatsuba(b, d);
    uint64_t ad_bc = karatsuba(a + b, c + d) - ac - bd;

    return ac * (uint64_t)pow(10, 2 * n) + ad_bc * (uint64_t)pow(10, n) + bd;
}

uint64_t multiply(uint64_t x, uint64_t y) {
    uint64_t result = 0;

    while (x > 0) {
        if (x & 1) {
            result += y;
        }
        x >>= 1;
        y <<= 1;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    uint64_t i = UINT64_MAX;
    uint64_t j = 10;

    clock_t t;
    clock_t m;
    clock_t l;
    int n = 9999999;

    t = clock();
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        multiply(i, j);
    }
    t = clock() - t;
    double time_taken = ((double)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Bit Manipulation Multiplication took %.15f seconds to execute in average\n", time_taken / n);

    m = clock();
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        uint64_t k_result = i * j;
    }
    m = clock() - m;
    double time_taken2 = ((double)m) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Regular Multiplication took %.15f seconds to execute in average\n", time_taken2 / n);

    l = clock();
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        karatsuba(i, j);
    }
    l = clock() - l;
    double time_taken3 = ((double)l) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Karatsuba Multiplication took %.15f seconds to execute in average\n", time_taken3 / n);

    printf("\nResults:\n");
    printf("Bit Manipulation Result: %llu\n", multiply(i, j));
    printf("Regular Multiplication Result: %llu\n", i * j);
    printf("Karatsuba Multiplication Result: %llu\n", karatsuba(i, j));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post an example output of your application? That would help us judge where things are slower than expected.

Comment: You wanted a faster way so you explicitly turned off all optimization. How does that make sense?

Comment: Your code involves log and pow. These functions are much slower than multiplication alone ! Not counting that your operands are tiny for Karatsuba.

Comment: Karatsuba algorithm is useful for very large numbers, not for 64-bit integers which your CPU has dedicated hardware for multiplying. Also, doing it in base 10 is very slow - the base should be a power of 2.

Comment: A modern Intel cpu can do 16 multiplications of `uint64_t` in a single clock cycle. Don't try to be faster, it's pointless.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Some compilers _might_ replace those with inline integer arithmetic. No guarantees though and definitely won't happen with optimizations disabled.

Comment: @Lundin: how do you want the compiler to replace the logs ? Also, integer divisions + modulos are criminally slow.

Comment: Also what does "M0 Assembly" mean? ARM Cortex M0? Knowing the core is highly relevant here, M0 does for example not have FPU and does not handle 64 bit arithmetic gracefully, so this code is _expected_ to run with poor performance on that core.

Comment: Optimize the algorithm, not multiplication itself.

Comment: I am working in a washing machine plant's R&D, thats why I can not share the code. But the code includes some multiplications with uint64_t, I wanted to find a faster way than regular multiplication, eventough it is fast, it causes flickers on the panel of the machine.

Comment: If we had something faster than the regular multiplication, it would *be* the regular multiplication.

Comment: About *"the code includes some multiplications"*, is there any chance that you can use a different algorithm, involving *less* multiplications or at least stored and reused partial results?

Comment: Used in a *washing machine* R&D? Is this a quantum calculation for teleportation or time travel?

Comment: @4DescarTes If 64-bit arithmetic is not supported by the HW, then the compiler implementers have probably done a decent job emulating it efficiently, so unless you can make some assumptions about the arguments, it is unlikely that you can do better. Another thing is that while the Karatsuba algorithm is *asymptotically* fast, it may not be the best choice for a fixed, relatively small-sized input, and, sorry to say, the way you implemented it is definitely very far from being fast. The processor works natively with binary numbers. This version of the algorithm works with decimal numbers.

Comment: If it's a washing machine with a Cortex M0 then don't benchmark as if it's a x86-64 PC. In particular, if you actually _need_ to do "advanced" math (logarithm, trigonometry etc) then you already picked the wrong MCU and it should have been a M4 or so. Benchmarking of embedded systems is done with oscilloscopes, period. Anything else is _the wrong way_. Furthermore from an embedded context, compiling as `-ffreestanding` might have significant impact on stuff like this.

Comment: Codes of the washing machine panel are written in C. I tried to run the code in Cortex M0 assembly just for trial purpose, I tought maybe the execution time might change there, but the results were same again. So washing machine has nothing to do with M0.

Comment: So you are trying to replace multiplication of uint64_t with some other function (your `karatsuba`) that (amongst other things such as floating point conversions and function calls) does several uint64_t multiplications.

Comment: I didn't really read about `karatsuba`, I just implemented it and it was slower. @PMF  said bit-shifting may be faster on earlier CPUs, so on monday I will try bit shifting instead of regular multiplication on real hardware, with the panel, which has an earlier CPU than my computer. If regular multiplication is faster, I will leave everything as it was.

Comment: The *flickers on the panel of the machine* might have a completely different cause that won't be solved by tinkering with multiplication.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am just an intern, so I don't know about that. But as experienced engineers of R&D team said, the speed of multiplication causes it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly your karatsuba algorithm is poor here, because it involves multiple floating point logarithm and pow functions. *Each one* of these is at best as fast as an integer multiplication, so that is clearly not an improvement here.

The bit-shift approach in your `multiply` function used to be faster on early CPUs (such as the Intel 8086), where a single 16 bit x 16 bit multiplication would take in the order of 150 clock cycles. But modern CPUs have been optimized a lot, so that a multiplication uses a lot fewer cycles. Details will vary by CPU type and exact assembly instructions used, but the bit-shift approach might eventually be faster for very short integers, so 8 or 16 bits, but cleraly not for 64 bit, where the loop overhead just adds, well, overhead.

Answer (score 4):

When you're multiplying 64-bit integers, normal multiplication is the fastest. If it weren't, we wouldn't use it.

To be honest, I don't understand why you're trying these weird methods.
Your function `multiply` requires jumping and `karatsuba` requires `log10`. Both are much slower then `mul` operation in the processor. I highly recommend reading and understanding how assembly and floating point arithmetic work. It's really worth it.